# How to make SmartGit/Hg find mercurial in a non-english system?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, internationalization, smartgit

I found a wonderful version control software in the internet which is called smartgit/hg.Before using it I have to set the executable path of git and hg.
The git executable path is automatically set to "/usr/bin/git",which is corrected.But the executable path of hg is always having some issue.When I set it to "/usr/bin/hg",smartgit/hg give me a wrong error that the executable path is wrong.
[image: error screenshot]

My Ubuntu version is 12.04LTS, SmartGit/Hg version is 4.5, Mercurial version is  2.0.2.JDK version is 1.7(OpenJDK)

Comment: Open up terminal and run `which hg`.

Comment: @Blender I have tried it, it returns "/usr/bin/hg"

Comment: Can you post the content of SmartGit/Hg's log.txt file which relates to the error message you see? See Help|About for the location of the log.txt file.

Comment: I have this too, my system is portuguese brazilian, and hg version message is localized. I suspect SmartGit/Hg is failing at that.

Answer (score 2):

please set your env language to be English(sorry, I have not reputation to show images).
smartgit/hg use 'hg --version' to get the version of hg, if your env language is not english,
it will be not get the version correctly.

after the smartgit/hg set hg executable path OK, you should rollback your env language.

Answer (score 1):

Find out where hg executable is and add that to the variable PATH.  You can look into the file .profile in your home directory to add the directory to the PATH as it should be defined there.

I tried to squint and read your error message but could only make out that Mercurial is not valid.  Can you transcribe the complete error in that window?

Comment: '/usr/bin/hg' seems to be not valid Mercurial executable.Mercurial version 1.8.1 or newer is required.(I have try to install oracle jdk instead of openjdk, but still get the wrong).

Comment: The hg executable is "/usr/bin/hg", I type "which hg" in the terminal to get it,so I think the PATH should be "/usr/bin",but it has been included in $PATH.It is possible that my mercurial version is too new?But I don't know how to install the old version one.

Comment: Since you are using Ubuntu, you may uninstall hg and Mercurial from Synaptic Manager and reinstall those.  If you install just Mercurial, it should also install the dependencies appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in SmartGit/Hg due to checking mercurial version through `hg --version` message and expecting english. In a portuguese brazilian system one gets:

```
$ hg --version 
Sistema de controle de versão distribuído Mercurial (versão 2.2.2) 
(veja http://mercurial.selenic.com para mais informações) 

Copyright (C) 2005-2012 Matt Mackall e outros 
Este software é livre; veja os fontes para condições de cópia. Não 
há garantias, nem mesmo de adequação para qualquer propósito em 
particular.
```

SmartGit/Hg fails on version verification in non-english languages.

Lastest build  solved this by setting `LANGUAGE` and `LANG` environment variables when executing `hg` for version verification, this solved the issue for me under Ubuntu 13.04.

**Resolution thread:**

http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/mercurial-executable-is-not-valid-td7573911.html